How to Exclude Selected Values from Other Dropdowns in Azure DevOps Work Items?
I'm working on an Azure DevOps extension where I have three dropdown inputs in a work item form. The requirement is that if a value is selected in one dropdown, that value should not be available in the other two dropdowns.
For example:

If Dropdown 1 is selected with "Value A", "Value A" should be removed from the options available in Dropdowns 2 and 3.
If Dropdown 2 is selected with "Value B", "Value B" should be removed from Dropdowns 1 and 3, and so on.

I need guidance on the best approach to achieve this functionality. Is there a way to dynamically update the options of the dropdowns based on the selections of the others in Azure DevOps work item form? Any example code or detailed steps would be highly appreciated.

Can you show some code about how you define the dropdown list? Please also have a check on similar ticket.

I achieved it with the reference of Multivalue control extension provided by microsoft
Here are the steps that can be followed:

Added an additional input in the azure-devops-extension.json file to specify the dependent dropdowns.
Filtered the options based on the dependent fields and displayed the results.

